# Scroll in navigation bar doesn't work in Material Design Lite v1.0.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design

I have used Material Design Lite to make navigation bar of site. But it have appeared that scroll of a menu doesn't work on mouse in Chrome and Safari, but it's okay in Mozilla Firefox.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Uses a header that scrolls with the text, rather than staying
      locked at the top -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--scroll">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
          <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <!-- Navigation -->
          <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOYKXK

Does anyone has any idea how can I get this scroll working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the script version from 1.0.5 to 1.0.2 worked for me.

So in your head-tag change

```
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.min.js"> </script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.2/material.min.js"></script>
```

The scroll function appears to be broken from v1.0.3 onwards. I don't know yet what causes the problem. If you find out, please post the answer here, I would like to know :)